# Android app button not working

Tags: java, android

I have used this snippet of code in a few other projects, but I cannot understand why it will not work here. It is a simple button that changes activities. The code is giving the error message: cannot resolve the symbol "setOnClickListener"

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

public static String value2;
public static String value3;
public static String value4;
public static String value5;
public static String value6;
public static String value7;
public static String value8;
public Spinner spinnerMath;
public Spinner spinnerEnglish;
public Spinner spinnerHistory;
public Spinner spinnerScience;
public Spinner spinnerLanguage;
public Spinner spinnerReligion;
public Spinner spinnerSeventh;
public Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of all check button = (Button) findviewById(R.id.......). Second you check Main2Activity have permission AndroidManifest.xml and layout.

Comment: change `this` to the activity context (`MainActivity.this`)

Comment: I ran it again and the new error message is <identifier> expected after "setOnClickListener" @Muhammad Hafiq Iqmal

Comment: I used the changes on one of my activities and it worked, the only difference between the activities is that the ones with buttons not working also has spinners and the one that works does not. Can that affect it? @Muhammad Hafiq Iqmal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your view id is the same with the one you want to click. replace `this` to `YOUR_CLASS.this`. If intent give you an error says something about manifest, then check you manifest if `Main2Activity.class` is declare as activity

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_name);    
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
          Log.i(TAG,"CLICKED");
          Intent intent = new Intent(YOUR_CLASS.this, Main2Activity.class);
          startActivity(intent);
      }
});
```

Comment: With every change I make, I still have the error message; cannot resolve the symbol "setOnClickListener"

Comment: can you post the error in your question..what error it gave you?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code it's hard to tell, but I'm suspicious of what 'this' is:

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);`
try

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Main2Activity.class);
```

or something similar, unless you've already taken that into account. Otherwise, your ClickListener code looks good to me.

Comment: With every change I make, I still have the error message; cannot resolve the symbol "setOnClickListener"